# Homestead in Ubuntu

Tags: php

I am editing my question regarding the benefits of Homestead vs. just installing each individual component without using Virtual box and/or Vagrant. I am new to Ubuntu --less than 2 weeks since I first installed-- and PHP so I appreciate any input. If you choose to use Homestead instead of just installing each of its components --PHP, SQL, etc..-- individually, can you update Homestead in one step using the command line in Ubuntu or do you have to update each of its components individually. If so, how do you do that? Your answer will help me to decide if I am going to install Homestead ---along with Virtual Box and Vagrant of course-- or not.

Answer (score 0):

The main motive I think is to created isolated dev/staging environments. You can also make use of containers e.g. Docker.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if using the Homestead box, you can be sure that every module is up on your server, and you wont have to manually install packages for making something (like certain artisan commands) work.

Comment: Thanks. I am brand new to Ubuntu and PHP. It sounds like Homestead/Vagrant/Virtual box is worth the time according to your answer. Do you know of any good tutorial about Homestead/Virtual Box/Vagrant on Ubuntu? I know there are tons of tutorials about everything on the net but it is hard to filter the good from the bad when you are new. Thank you again and I hope I did not violate any guideline here.

Comment: Laracasts has some great tutorials about setting up your Homestead enviromnent, although some of them are paid.

Comment: Thanks. I would vote you up but I don't have the 15 points required yet to be able to do that.